# Cat has bare area where collar rubbed

Tags: cats, hairloss, collar

Our cat has a bald area due to a collar being a little to tight. She gained weight and I realized it later than I should have.

Her hair has never grown back, and her collar is loose now. I am not sure what to do.  Is there a way to get the hair to grow back?

Comment: Can you add a photo? Also, it would help if you share the collar too if you bought it online.

Answer (score 2):

**Try different collars.**

You should check the skin for any signs of irritation, abrasion, redness, and so forth. These could be signs of an allergy or some such. If you notice any obvious signs of an allergic reaction, or if you notice the cat scratches a lot around the collar, then try collars made of different materials. You may want to try this as a first step regardless, because sometimes allergic reactions aren't visibly obvious.

**Remove the collar entirely.**

It may be that even though the collar is nice and loose now it's still rubbing the new fur off. The only solution then is to remove the collar entirely. Make sure to get your cat microchipped if it isn't already, as without the collar that will be the only way to identify it.

**Ask your vet.**

There are some illnesses in cats that make the hair particularly brittle or easily pulled out, so if the problem persists, it's worth it to ask your vet during the next visit. However, I don't consider it of particular concern unless you notice other symptoms along with the hair loss only around the collar. So I do not think it is necessary to schedule a vet appointment just for the hair loss in that area only.